# localstorage not retaining data after page reload

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to retain data in a localstorage after reload but it is not working 
this is my attempt

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem(name, $('#inputName').val());

}


window.onload = function() {

    var name = localStorage.getItem(name);
    if (name !== null) $('#inputName').val(name);
    alert(name);


}

</script>
<html>

<body>

 <input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" required>


</body>

</html>
```

on refreshing the page after entering data on the form it keeps alerting null. kindly assist

Comment: Are you setting the value correctly? localStorage.setItem('name', val)

Comment: keys for localstorage should be strings.

Comment: the above is a complete snippet of mine

Comment: Is this accurate? Your script tag NOT in the `head`? or the html for that matter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onbeforeunload`, `name` is the name of the window (because you haven't given it any other value, and browsers have a global `name` property which is the name of the window — it's usually blank).

In this line:

```
var name = localStorage.getItem(name);
```

...it's `undefined`, because of the `var name`.

You need to use a proper name, for instance:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem("your-setting-name", $('#inputName').val());
};

window.onload = function() {
    var name = localStorage.getItem("your-setting-name");
    if (name !== null) $('#inputName').val(name);
    alert(name);
};
```

Also note charlietfl's oint that if you don't want to alert `null` on the first visit to the page, you need to put the `alert` in the body of the `if`:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var name = localStorage.getItem("your-setting-name");
    if (name !== null) {
        $('#inputName').val(name);
        alert(name);
    }
};
```

Otherwise, it'll alert `null` on the first visit and then whatever the last value was otherwise.

(Also note that I've added some missing `;`. Automatic Semicolon Insertion will add these particular ones, but it's an error-correction mechanism, so I'd advise not relying on it.)

---

Other issues:

- You're using jQuery functions, but haven't shown any script tag including jQuery on the page.
- You have the closing `</html>` tag **before** the `<input ...>` tag.

---

Here's a fiddle with the above fixed (can't use Stack Snippets with local storage): https://jsfiddle.net/un86not0/ Full working page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem("your-setting-name", $('#inputName').val());
};

window.onload = function() {
    var name = localStorage.getItem("your-setting-name");
    if (name !== null) {
        $('#inputName').val(name);
        alert(name);
    }
};
</script>
<input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" required>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You type faster than me :)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss :-) The second-best advice my mother gave me in high school: "You're into computers, take a typing class."

Comment: still thesame result, alerts null

Comment: also suggest OP get used to using `{}` with `if()` as alert will always fire regardless of conditional

Comment: the alert did not fire on doing this >>>>>> if (name !== null){ $('#inputName').val(name);
    alert(name);}

Comment: @parker because the `{}` make the execution different than what you have in question. Only the first block after `if()` will be conditional when you don't use `{}` and for that reason it is a poor practice not to use `{}`

Comment: @parker: There are other issues as well, I've flagged them up. Correcting all of them does solve the problem.

Comment: LOL I only type about 45 wpm when coding.  I once watched a nice lady put up nearly 180 and realized I was NOT her.  Like nearly everything, the top performer in anything only give us goals to attempt to exceed.  Interesting to note the QWERTY keyboards were designed to slow us down on manual typewriters to keep them from jambing.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: Yeah. Having poisoned my muscle memory with qwerty, I've never worked up the courage to try dvorak or similar. :-)

Comment: Hence "standards" entrenchment - once in place there must be nearly universal significant boosts to have value to change (like the original jambs did  that, and people complain regarding the JavaScript original standards but now it is somewhat entrenched.

Comment: @parker: Your comments on another answer suggest you still haven't implemented the above. If you do, it **does** work: https://pastebin.com/BdhiKDPW (can't use jsFiddle or similar with local storage). **Edit:** Oh, hey, looks like you can: https://jsfiddle.net/un86not0/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder how can I clear this localstorage after use

Comment: @parker: Have you looked [in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#dom-storage-removeitem) or on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323392/trying-to-remove-item-from-localstorage-using-the-key-name

Answer (score -1):

The variable `name` haven't been initiated yet you already used it as a value reference. Maybe it wasn't working well because of that?

Here in this solution, you can separately reference the local storage item without using the variable `name` which might have caused it not to work.

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('myItem', $('#inputName').val());

}


window.onload = function() {

    var name = localStorage.getItem('myItem');
    if (name !== null) $('#inputName').val(name);
    alert(name);
}

</script>
```

Comment: it does not retain the data on page refresh

Comment: @Abel: Why? What did you change? Why did you change it? Code dumps are not *useful* answers, especially when they just duplicate an existing answer that has explanation.

Comment: " if it works" please explain why you are guessing here.