# trying to remove item from localstorage using the key name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I am trying to remove item from localstorage or rather clear it on button click. I have written the code but on clicking on the button, it does not clear the localstorage data. this is the variable with the localstorage data

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem("first_name", $('#inputName').val());
};
```

**EDITTED**

```
window.onload = function() {
    var name = localStorage.getItem("first_name");
    if (name !== null) {
        $('#inputName').val(name);
        alert(name);
    }
};
```

this is the function to clear storage

```
function clearStorage(){
alert('localstorage cleared!');
localStorage.removeItem('first_name');
```

}

the snippet of the button click code block to clear localstorage data using the key-name

```
<input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" required>
<button onclick="clearStorage()">clear</button>
```

on clicking the button in attempt to wipe out the data from the localstorage and refreshing the page, the localstorage data is still in the input value.
how to clear localstorage content is my challenge

Comment: Where are you setting the input's value? Try creating a fiddle demonstrating this issue.

Comment: How and when is your set item invoked? Do you see the alert of the clearstorage?

Comment: check my edits.

Comment: @Christoph yes I do

Comment: Is the `button` element within a form?

Comment: yes it is.......

Comment: could it be - that it gets removed but due to your `window.onbeforeunload = function() {` it gets added again and cause button is submit (by default without type) will reload with your item in local storage?!

Comment: @parker then your form is causing a page redirect/reload, hence the items gets immediately added back in to localstorage

Comment: so how do I go about this because by default input types are found in a form

Comment: Hi, In `window.onbeforeunload`, I don't think you are saving anything because `$('#inputName').val()` will not have any value..

Comment: That depends on exactly what you want to achieve. Your question doesn't give enough information

Comment: using the snippet abov I want to clear the locastorage data on button click

Comment: try adding type="button" to the button. that will prevent reloading the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're successfully removing the item — and then when you refresh, you're **setting** it again as you leave the page, because you still have:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem("first_name", $('#inputName').val());
};
```

You'll have to decide when you want to set the item. The above will always do it, even if you've cleared it previously.

Perhaps you'd be better off only setting the item when the `input` changes, and **not** in `onbeforeunload`. That is, getting rid of the above, and instead:

```
$("#inputName").on("input", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("first_name", $(this).val());
});
```

That way, if you clear the item (remove it from local storage), it won't get added back unless you edit the field again.

Comment: tried your snippet on refreshing the page, is alert null

Comment: @parker: No, it doesn't: https://jsfiddle.net/un86not0/1/ (I was missing a `#` in the `on` statement, but that doesn't make it alert `null`.)

Comment: sure thought as much but the clearing is not real time I had to refresh the page before it is cleared after clicking the button

Comment: @parker: Clearing the local storage is indeed realtime. If you want the `input` to be changed, you have to add code to do that. There's nothing magically linking the `input` to `localStorage`; that's the job of your code.

Comment: @parker: Ask yourself: How do I set the value of an `input`?

Answer (score 0):

The code for setting/clearing the local storage looks good. However, the input field is not real-time synched with your local storage so, if you want your input to be always up to date with your local storage value, you should update it inside the `clearStorage` function in this way. Also you don't need to refresh the page if you use this approach:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var name = fetchLocalStorage();

  if (name !== null) {
    $('#inputName').val(name);
    alert(name);
  }
};

function fetchLocalStorage() {
  return localStorage.getItem("first_name");
}

function clearStorage() {
  // clear local storage
  localStorage.removeItem('first_name');
  alert('localstorage cleared!');

  // update input value
  var name = fetchLocalStorage();
  $('#inputName').val(name);
}

function saveStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem("first_name", $('#inputName').val());
}
```

And the HTML should be updated to:

```
<input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" required>
<button type="button" onclick="saveStorage()">save</button>
<button type="button" onclick="clearStorage()">clear</button>
```

Comment: using your approach the localstorage is not stored. I needed if I refresh the page let the localstroge data be held and it should be cleared only on clicking the clear button

Comment: correct, the localstorage is not stored becasue I didn't implement the localStorage.setItem method in my snippet. I can't understand how that part works as the input field is initially "Empty" by default when you refresh the page. I believe you need another button for saving those information inside the local storage. Something like" `<button onclick="saveStorage()">save</button>` `function saveStorage() { localStorage.setItem("first_name", $('#inputName').val()); }`
Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Updated. Have a look

Comment: i think for some reason I needed that unbeforeload function

Answer (score -1):

uhm, try adding `type="button"` to your button...
this prevents the form submit + page reload + onbeforeunload -> where your storage item gets set every time...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type

Comment: added type button but still did not work>>>>>>
<button type="button" onclick="clearStorage()">clear</button>

Comment: did you checked via debugger (set a breakpoint one line after `localStorage.removeItem('first_name');`) and check if your item got removed - it should definitely be removed!!! but on your onbeforeunload u add it each time again - + remove onbeforunload - u should see it will work ;)